# Loop minutes and echo with bash

Tags: bash, date

I want to iterate all the minutes in a month (the purpose will be to generate a CSV file).

But when I try this:

```
d="2016-09-01 00:00:00"
 while [ "$d" != "2016-09-30 00:00:00" ]; do
 echo $d 
 d=$(date --utc "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00" -d "$d + 1 minute" )
done
```

Both the hour and minute are being incremented:

```
2016-09-01 00:00:00
2016-09-01 01:01:00
2016-09-01 02:02:00
2016-09-01 03:03:00
2016-09-01 04:04:00
2016-09-01 05:05:00
2016-09-01 06:06:00
2016-09-01 07:07:00
2016-09-01 08:08:00
```

What am I doing wrong and how to correctly loop minutes?

Comment: Interestingly, when I run this code, the hour *decrements* while the minute increments. What time zone are you in? I suspect `--utc` is only applying to the output, not the date arithmetic.

Comment: Yeah the + sign doesn't work how people think. Try just `+ minute` or just `minute`, and just `+ 1`. `+` adds an offset on the time. Don't use `+` just put the increment after e.g `$d 10 minutes`

Answer (score 0):

I would work with Unix timestamps instead.

```
d=$(date --utc +%s -d "2016-09-01 00:00:00")
end=$(date --utc +%s -d "2016-09-30 00:00:00")
while [ "$d" != "$end" ]; do
    date --utc "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00" -d "@$d"
    d=$(( d + 60 ))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add **timezone** `UTC` after your date string variable `$d` to get the right output:

```
d="2016-09-01 00:00:00"
for ((i=0; i<=60; i++)); do
   date --utc -d "$d UTC + $i minute"
done

Thu Sep  1 00:00:00 UTC 2016
Thu Sep  1 00:01:00 UTC 2016
Thu Sep  1 00:02:00 UTC 2016
Thu Sep  1 00:03:00 UTC 2016
Thu Sep  1 00:04:00 UTC 2016
Thu Sep  1 00:05:00 UTC 2016
...
...
Thu Sep  1 00:55:00 UTC 2016
Thu Sep  1 00:56:00 UTC 2016
Thu Sep  1 00:57:00 UTC 2016
Thu Sep  1 00:58:00 UTC 2016
Thu Sep  1 00:59:00 UTC 2016
Thu Sep  1 01:00:00 UTC 2016
```

Note use of `UTC` after `$d`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `+` after a time component in the date string is used for ' [time zone correction](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_chapter/tar_7.html)' not for doing what you want to do. Interestingly, inverting date and time works:

```
$ date  "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00" -d "21:31:00 2016-09-03 + 1 minute  "
2016-09-03 21:32:00
```

while the other way around messes with timezones and offsets so the result might depend on your local configuration:

```
$ TZ=Europe/London date  "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00" -d "2016-09-03 21:32:00 + 1 minute "
2016-09-03 21:33:00
$ TZ=Europe/Brussels date  "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00" -d "2016-09-03 21:32:00 + 1 minute "
2016-09-03 22:33:00
$ TZ=Asia/Singapore date  "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00" -d "2016-09-03 21:32:00 + 1 minute "
2016-09-04 04:33:00
```